# Change in query find() parameter through out the whole project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, automatic-updates

I filtered whole database collection in query based on whole project

```
model.find({isDeleted : false})
```

Now I want to filter every collection in query based on

```
model.find({isDeleted : false , createdBy : "company_name"})
```

I have to make changes in more than 30 files to do so.
I would like to know How to make changes in one place that help in retriving based on second condition in find()

Answer (score 0):

Please update your find query with this:

```
await model.find({ createdBy: 'company_name', isDeleted: false }).exec();
```

it will help you to fetch data is like company_name which is false by isDeleted.